# How do you create externally facing URLs using bound helpers?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following:

```
<a target = "_blank" href="{{ createUrl param1 param2 param3 }}"> [ Click here ]</a>
```

Param1, param2, and param3 change depending on other factors. This needs to be handled by a bound helper. So I have, for example:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper 'createUrl', (param1, param2, param3) ->  
  return "https://exampleurl.net/query=" + param1?.toString() + param2?.toString() + param3?.toString()
```

The URL it generates when clicking on this (sample, without the parameters): `https://localhost:8443/%3Cscript%20id='metamorph-53-start'%20type='text/x-placeholder'%3E%3C/script%3Ehttps://exampleurl.net/query=%3Cscript%20id='metamorph-53-end'%20type='text/x-placeholder'%3E%3C/script%3E`

How can I make it go to the external url instead? I want to generate a URL that isn't altered by Ember: in this case, simply "https://exampleurl.net/query="

Comment: Upgrade your ember version, metamorph scripts have been removed and handlebars has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using an old version of Ember, so here's the solution:

You can define computed property on your controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   param1: "",
   param2: "",
   param3: "",
   externalUrl: Ember.computed('param1', 'param2', 'param3', function(){
       return "https://exampleurl.net/query=" + this.get('param1') + this.get('param2') + this.get('param3');
   });
});
```

And then bind it in your template:

```
<a target = "_blank" {{bind-attr href=externalUrl}}"> [ Click here ]</a>
```

If you feel it has to be more abstract and reused in different controllers, the same could be implemented as a component.

Answer (score 0):

In Ember 2.0 you can do:

```
<a target = "_blank" href="{{ createUrl param1 param2 param3 }}"> [ Click here ]</a>
```

Assuming `createUrl` is defined helper.

Upgrade your application's Ember version to the latest one.

Comment: Did you mean to copy/paste something else? This is the first line of code in my question. I have registered a bound helper in my question as well.

Comment: I mean use latest Ember version.